# Django order by custom list

Tags: django

I have problem of ordering the queryset.

For example, it will be sorted desc.

If they have same priority so can't define specific order, they will use second priority.

```
# list = [[id, priority], ...]

list_1 = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,3],[4,4]] # first priority

list_2 = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,7],[4,2]] # second priority


using first priority : 4 -> (2,3) -> 1

using second priority : 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1

result = 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

So i want to get queryset, ordered like result id sequence.

Comment: Can you share the queryset and models?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is the best way to solve this problem.

But it worked to me so hope this code is helpful to you.

```
    _count = [2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 8]
   ordering = []
   ordering.append(Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(_count)]))
```

pk is the field name. In my code pk is the Primary key in model. If you want to ordering by name you can change the pk to name.

And then is the position of the pk.

```
Model.objects.all().order_by(*ordering)
```

After setting ordering list you can apply that condition in query like upper code.

I can not sure but condition order is important as well.

Because that condition effect in turn of list value.

+) I am not good at English, but i do my best to explain my code. So if i have wrong thing in my answer, please comment me.